# Combine result of same user into one result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, sql-server-2014

I try to combine my result whereby If "txtApplName" and "LeaveTypeDesc" are same, the total days should add and show after plus the "Totaldays".

Example, in image  record number 6 and 7 should combine the result and the "txtApplTotalDays" should be added. I'm stuck here. By the way, I'm using SQL Server 2014.

```
select txtApplName, type.LeaveTypeDesc, department.DeptName, txtManagerName, final.txtApplTotalDays, final.txtApplLeaveStartDate, final.txtApplLeaveEndDate
from [dbo].[EN_TBL_FINAL_FORM] final 
INNER JOIN EN_TBL_MAST_DEPARTMENT department on final.lstApplDepartment = department.DeptID
INNER JOIN EN_TBL_MAST_LEAVETYPE type on final.lstApplLeaveType =type.LeaveTypeID 
where final.txtApplLeaveStartDate >= 'GETDATE()-10' and final.txtApplLeaveEndDate <= 'GETDATE()'
```

[image: Below are image of my result from sql query.]

```
Sample Data:

txtApplName  LeaveTypeDesc     DeptName    txtManagerName    txtApplTotalDays
                     
Ng            Hospitalization  Development    PH               2.0
Aqila         Maternity Leave    Human        ELE              1.0
Sharah        Annual Leave      Human         ELE              1.0
Sharah        Annual Leave      Human         ELE              1.0
Aqilah        Annual Leave      Human         ELE              1.0


Expected Data:

txtApplName  LeaveTypeDesc     DeptName    txtManagerName    txtApplTotalDays
                     
Ng            Hospitalization  Development    PH                2.0
Aqilah        Maternity Leave    Human        ELE               1.0
Sharah        Annual Leave      Human         ELE               2.0
Aqila         Annual Leave      Human         ELE               1.0
```

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results, both as formatted text, or ever better DDL/DML statements, but not images. I recommend using a shorter (1 or 2 char) alias, the intention is to make the query more concise. And I recommend being consistent with your casing, choose whether you are using lower or upper case (or a mix) but then use it consistently. It will make your query much easier to read. And whats the criteria for merging those 2 records, and what start date would be used?

Comment: the query I posted still on testing phase, What I trying to achieve is if LeaveTypeDesc and txtApplName are same, the record should show only one record but txtAppltotalDays should be added.

Comment: I edited the original post and i added sample data and expected results as well.

NOTE: date can be random, i can select any date i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `GROUP BY`. For the sample data provided you can use the below query to achieve your expected result.

```
SELECT txtApplName,LeaveTypeDesc, DeptName,txtManagerName,SUM(txtApplTotalDays)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY txtApplName,LeaveTypeDesc, DeptName,txtManagerName
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff : I marked as correct answer but stack overflow decline my vote.

Comment: @lugkenish. You need to click the tick mark below the vote option to accept the answer. Check this link [How do I accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)